# Unable to define a variable - discord.js (v12)

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a ticket system handled by the bot. Once a ticket channel is created, the bot will send a message and the person will have to choose an option.
The code is almost done, but I need some help with the `channelCreated` variable because I can't define it (the variable that tells the bot when a channel is created).

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const infoembedColor = "#4747f8"
const fs = require('fs')
const {
  Message
} = require("discord.js");

module.exports = async(client, args, message) => {
  console.log("\nJade - I am Online!\n")

  client.user.setStatus('online')
  client.user.setActivity('Calympia', {
    type: 'WATCHING'
  })

  if (client.guilds.cache.find(guild => guild.name === "Calympia")) {
    if (await channelCreated) {

      const ticketEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(infoembedColor)
        .setTitle(`Welcome to Calympia's Support`)
        .setDescription(`Welcome! Please specify a reason behind opening this ticket.`)
        .addFields({
          name: "Appeal for a mute or a ban",
          value: "*Reply with* \`Appeal\`"
        }, {
          name: "Apply for Staff",
          value: "*Reply with* \`Apply\`"
        }, {
          name: "Questions, Suggestions, Queries",
          value: "*Reply with* \`Basic\`"
        }, {
          name: "Report a rule-breaker",
          value: "*Reply with* \`Report\`"
        }, {
          name: "Anything else.",
          value: "*Reply with* \`Other\`"
        })
      await channel.send({
        embed: ticketEmbed
      })

      let ticketAppeal = ["appeal", "Appeal"];
      let foundInText1 = false;
      for (var i in ticketAppeal) {
        if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(ticketAppeal[i].toLowerCase())) foundInText1 = true;
      }
      if (foundInText1) {
        await message.channel.send("Alright. 1")
      }

      let ticketApply = ["apply", "Apply", "want to become staff", "want to apply for staff", "want to apply"];
      let foundInText2 = false;
      for (var i in ticketApply) {
        if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(ticketApply[i].toLowerCase())) foundInText2 = true;
      }
      if (foundInText2) {
        await message.channel.send("Alright. 2")
      }

      let ticketBasic = ["basic", "Basic", "question", "query", "queries", "suggest"];
      let foundInText3 = false;
      for (var i in ticketBasic) {
        if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(ticketBasic[i].toLowerCase())) foundInText3 = true;
      }
      if (foundInText3) {
        await message.channel.send("Alright. 3")
      }

      let ticketReport = ["report", "Report"];
      let foundInText4 = false;
      for (var i in ticketReport) {
        if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(ticketReport[i].toLowerCase())) foundInText4 = true;
      }
      if (foundInText4) {
        await message.channel.send("Alright. 4")
      }

      let ticketOther = ["other", "anything else"];
      let foundInText5 = false;
      for (var i in ticketOther) {
        if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(ticketOther[i].toLowerCase())) foundInText5 = true;
      }
      if (foundInText5) {
        await message.channel.send("Alright. 5")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use something like `!ticket <reason>`.